# Word for skill without passion

Tags: meaning, word-choice, single-word-requests

I am looking for a word that describes a skill a person possesses but does not enjoy. For example:

> Although Robert does not like tennis, he is very good at it.

What word could be used to describe Robert's skill?

Comment: Talent without passion is a job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A natural **[talent](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Talent)** for something, but with no passion. A wasted talent in this specific case.

- Natural endowment or ability of a superior quality.

Answer (score 0):

Consider *gift*.

> [gift](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/gift): a special ability or capacity; natural endowment; talent

Alternately, you could also use the noun *natural*.

> [natural](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/natural): one having natural skills, talents, or abilities.
>
> *Although Robert doesn't like tennis, he is a natural at it.*

Answer (score 0):

Robert is a tennis *automaton*.